# How specify in VC2008 does not rearrange segments in resulting binary file every rebuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have issue with CPP Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0
I have an VC2008 project that make small executable windows service application.
But after every clean&rebild VC2008 makes binary file with same size, but randomly rearrange segments inside (physycally inbinary address of segment .rdata in IDA moves +/-30h).

How I can specify always keep use rule or addreses for placement segments in resulting binary file or it is impossible?

Comment: There's `/ORDER` but that affects functions, not `.rdata`. Still, if the data segment moves because functions before it move, then that might just work. Still, lots of work.